# How to write my answer in a variable?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have a problem with writing my code dynamic. I am doing a course in javascript programming and I am having some struggles with the final part of one assignment.

> Exercise 8.2
>
> Extend your switch-case statement with a default value. The result should
>     be 'That is an unknown fruit.' when the variable 'myFruit' has an unknown
>     value. Answer with the result where 'myFruit = pear'.
>
> Write your code below and put the answer into the variable ANSWER.

```
var myFruit = "pear";
switch (myFruit) {
  case "banana":
  console.log("The banana is yellow.");
  break;
  case "apple":
  console.log("The apple is green.");
  break;
  case "kiwi":
  console.log("The kiwi is green.");
  break;
  case "plum":
  console.log("The plum is purple");
  break;
  default:
  console.log("That is an unknown fruit.");
  break;}
```

How do I formulate this result in a variable?

I have tried to write like this:

```
var result = switch (myFruit);
```

But that does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can declare the `result` variable, and inside the switch statement cases, instead of `console.log`ging the result, you can assign the value to the `result` variable, like so:

```
var myFruit = "pear";
var result;
switch (myFruit) {
  case "banana":
      result = "The banana is yellow.";
      break;
  case "apple":
      result = "The apple is green.";
      break;
  case "kiwi":
      result = "The kiwi is green.";
      break;
  case "plum":
      result = "The plum is purple";
      break;
  default:
      result = "That is an unknown fruit.";
      break;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uqxtmc25/

Answer (score 1):

I won't write out all the code for you, but point you in the right direction.  You need to set the text in a variable and return it:

```
switch ..

    case "something":
        var message = "Your message here.";
        break;

...
```

Once your switch sets the value, then you use it as you need to.

You cannot return a value from a switch statement by using the switch statement like an operation.

Comment: It's nice that you're trying to push him to learn by himself, but I think that Stack Overflow isn't the perfect place for that. Stack Overflow is a place where others users with same or similar problem can find their solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can not call the switch statement like `var result = switch (myFruit);`, it is not a function. You would have to move all the switch case code into a function:

```
function mySwitchCase(fruit){
    var returnResult='';
    switch (fruit) {
        case "banana":
           returnResult="The banana is yellow.";
            break;
        case "apple":
            returnResult="The apple is green.";
            break;
        case "kiwi":
            returnResult"The kiwi is green.";
            break;
        case "plum":
            returnResult"The plum is purple";
            break;
        default:
            returnResult"That is an unknown fruit.";
            break;
    }
    return returnResult;
}
```

then you can call it like this:

```
var result = mySwitchCase(myFruit);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the result in a variable `answer` and then use that variables to print out the result;

```
function fruitSwitcher (myFruit) {
    var answer = "That is an unknown fruit.";
    switch (myFruit) {
      case "banana":
      answer = "The banana is yellow.";
      break;
      case "apple":
      answer = "The apple is green.";
      break;
      case "kiwi":
      answer ="The kiwi is green.";
      break;
      case "plum":
      answer = "The plum is purple";
      break;
      default: 
      // no really needed
      answer ="That is an unknown fruit.";
      break;
     }

     return answer;
}

var myFruit = "pear";
var answer = fruitSwitcher(myFruit);
console.log(answer); //That is an unknown fruit.
```

The default case in the previous code is superfluous as the variable `answer` is initialised to a default value. If an unknown fruit in passed in input, none of the switch cases matches it and, therefore, the `answer` variables never changes value and the function returns the default value.

Comment: Please explain your answers, don't just dump out code

Comment: I update the answer, btw it is just a switch statement.

Comment: Why is the default case not really needed?

Comment: Because the variable `answer` is initialised to a default value. If you pass in input an unknown fruit, none of the switch cases matches and the resulting value is the default value.

Comment: Since the exercise specifically said to add a default case, why would you initialize the variable? That's redundant.